# Geting values in Me. from a For Each loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have some problems... I'm new to VBA.
So... I have a small application wich has a bunch of ComboBoxes... most of them have the same values from a Range in Excel.
So I want to get the values in the Comboboxes with a small code and here it is

```
Dim rep As Range
Dim cbox As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Each rep In ws.Range("Repere")
  For Each cbox In ws2.Range("cboxs")
    With Me.cbox.Value
    .AddItem rep.Value
    End With
  Next cbox
Next rep
```

The problem is that this thing doesn't work ... it seems that Me.cbox.Value is not correct. What I want to do with Me.cbox.Value is to have something like Me.Combobox1, Me.Combobox2, Me.Combobox3 and so on... in the Range cboxs are the names of the Comboboxes...
So I want to load the data from the Range "Repere" in every Combobox... (I have about 40 in the app)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you should not be using the value property. You're intention is to use the addItem method of the combobox from your for loop, but you are attempting to call the method on Me.cbox.Value. It should be

```
For Each cbox In ws2.Range("cboxs")
  Me.Controls(cbox.Value).AddItem rep.Value "<-----no need for the with bloc at all
  End With
Next cbox
```

good luck!

Comment: .Range("cboxs") is a range containing the names of the combo boxes, so the cbox variable is simply a cell containing one name - it's not the combo box itself

Comment: I see, then probably Gary's form of Me.Controls(cbox.value).additem repValue is the correct answer. I still think the With Block is misplaced or unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try `With Me.Controls(cbox.Value)`.